# Oracle 11g SQL Ticket Time in Status

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to calculate the time a ticket has spent in each status, but only have the date time stamp for when the ticket was initially put in the status. The next record for the ticket will be a different status with a rowstamp and datetime > than the the first rowstamp and datetime and the same ticket number. A sample for two tickets is below:

```
Ticket  STATUS  CHANGEDATE        CHANGEBY   STATUSID   PARENT  ROWSTAMP
1256    PENDING 27-JAN-17 10.29.05  Steve   20265288    1256    15261227238
1256    QUEUED  27-JAN-17 07.33.37  Steve   20263810    1256    15259925905
1256    REWORK  26-JAN-17 08.46.27  Steve   20261523    1256    15255531117
1256    SUBMITTED   26-JAN-17 03.02.57  Steve   20259551    1256    15253362461
1256    QUEUED  24-JAN-17 08.35.22  Steve   20241287    1256    15228220003
1256    REWORK  22-JAN-17 07.07.08  Steve   20229359    1256    15211303360
1256    SUBMITTED   20-JAN-17 03.29.48  Steve   20226100    1256    15190853552
1256    PENDING 12-JAN-17 11.16.31  Steve   20179545    1256    15105790542
1256    QUEUED  10-JAN-17 08.09.25  Steve   20161878    1256    15082495955
1256    REWORK  09-JAN-17 06.59.37  Steve   20159040    1256    15076785748
1256    SUBMITTED   09-JAN-17 01.58.22  Steve   20157016    1256    15074491733
1256    QUEUED  09-JAN-17 01.19.58  Steve   20152389    1256    15069093940
1256    WAPPR   09-JAN-17 01.14.29  Steve   20152381    1256    15068979212
1875    PENDING 16-JAN-17 10.55.36  Mike    20193876    1875    15143974636
1875    INPRG   09-JAN-17 12.18.47  Mike    20156411    1875    15073870918
1875    QUEUED  09-JAN-17 05.54.15  Mike    20153527    1875    15070925155
1875    WAPPR   06-JAN-17 06.19.27  Mike    20145566    1875    15050402194
```

I have no idea where to I worked with a previous data set that had the start and end time for each status in the same record. But not just the start time.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Just use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(changedate) over (partition by ticket order by changedate) as next_changedate
from tickets t;
```

I'm not sure how you want to calculate the difference.  You can just subtract the two values and get the difference in days.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and help with the formatting!